# How do you say as you can see?

Tags: translation, verbs

I've found other ways to say "as you can see" but most of them are the literate verb to see 見てる. I'm trying to explain something in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the formality of the audience, but the expected translations in a formal register would be ご覧の通り or ご覧のように, with 見ての通り being a possibility in a more relaxed register.

Comment: I kept digging further and found 分かるよう Is that acceptable?